# Change location of .gitconfig in Visual Studio

Tags: git, windows-registry, cygwin, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 has Git integration, but it picks up a .gitconfig file used in my Cygwin install that has some problems (for one thing, it is a symlink, but even it if was a normal file it would have wrong line endings). I would like to specify another location for it, but I am unable to find the correct setting.

There must be some Registry setting for this, as my Cygwin home dir is deeply hidden within some Chocolatey install.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio finds the .gitconfig file using the %HOME% environment variable. By default its value is the same as %USERPROFILE%, but you can change it and create a new .gitconfig there to your liking.

Win button -> type "variables" -> select "Edit environment variables for your account"

If you don't have a %HOME% variable, you can create one for free on the same window.

You can't create files starting with a period through Explorer, but you can using any (decent) text editor, like Notepad++.

Alternatively, you can create a .gitconfig on the local repo itself, and options there will supersede the ones on your Cygwin install. However, you will have to do that for each repo.

Comment: %HOME% doesn't exist on my Windows 7 system. If I try to create a file in %USERPROFILE% called ".gitconfig" it fails, telling me that filenames must not start with a period (.).

Comment: I needed a restart in Windows for this to work